# How to insert closing node for an element in XML structure in BizTalk

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have been trying to insert a closing node in BizTalk XML output using map but I am not able to do that.

Present output is which I am getting right now. In this I have query in highlighted part.  And what I need is expected output with the help of mapping.

Present Output

```
<VIS_Products Version="1.0">
    <Product>
        <ProductNo>200042132</ProductNo>
        <LotTrackingCode>1</LotTrackingCode>
        <SerialTrackingCode>0</SerialTrackingCode>
        <FractionAllowed>false</FractionAllowed>
        <RevisionControlFlag>false</RevisionControlFlag>
        <DefaultUomCode>MTR</DefaultUomCode>
        <ProductInventoryType>8</ProductInventoryType>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <FUID>
        </FUID>
        <TextID>
            <Text>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1033</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1036</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1046</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>2058</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
            </Text>
        </TextID>
        <ProductGroupDelete>
            <Group>VIS_Nojax</Group>
            <GroupType>2</GroupType>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <GroupClassID Name="VIS_ProductLine /">
            </ProductID>
        </ProductGroupDelete>
        <ProductGroupDelete>
    </Product>
</VIS_Products >
```

Expected Output

```
 <VIS_Products Version="1.0">
        <Product>
        <ProductNo>200042132</ProductNo>
        <LotTrackingCode>1</LotTrackingCode>
        <SerialTrackingCode>0</SerialTrackingCode>
        <FractionAllowed>false</FractionAllowed>
        <RevisionControlFlag>false</RevisionControlFlag>
        <DefaultUomCode>MTR</DefaultUomCode>
        <ProductInventoryType>8</ProductInventoryType>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <FUID>
        </FUID>
        <TextID>
            <Text>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1033</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1036</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>1046</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
                <TextTranslation>
                    <LanguageID>2058</LanguageID>
                    <Short>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Short>
                    <Medium>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Medium>
                    <Extended>NJREG SF 30 U70 CLR PTR P</Extended>
                    <TextID>
                    </TextID>
                </TextTranslation>
            </Text>
        </TextID>
        <ProductGroupDelete>
            <Group>VIS_Nojax</Group>
            <GroupType>2</GroupType>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <GroupClassID Name="VIS_ProductLine">
            </GroupClassID>
            <ProductID>
            </ProductID>
        </ProductGroupDelete>
        <ProductGroupDelete>
    </Product>
</VIS_Products >
```

The changes are in group class id node in `productgroupdelete`. In the present output I am not getting the closing node. I want closing node with the help of mapping.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that your last <ProductGroupDelete> element (3rd last line) is incorrect in both cases. Perhaps a formatting issue?

Answer (score 1):

Self closing tags, like `<GroupClassID Name="VIS_ProductLine" />` are identical as `<GroupClassID Name="VIS_ProductLine"></GroupClassID>`. The XSLT processor will choose what suits best for it. In writing it is the same.

You could try to trick the XSLT processor and add for example `<xsl:comment />` if you really want to be displayed as you requested. For example this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GroupClassID">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:comment>TRICKED</xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It adds a comment as child of that node and the output will add a closing tag.